# Android alert dialog not styled properly on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have tried everything to get this working and cannot figure it out.

I am trying to use an alert dialog im my app. It works fine on KitKat but not on Lollipop.

I have even tried using many material dialogs on GitHub and again they work on Kitkat but not on Lollipop.

I am testing on my Nexus 5 with stock nexus factory image.

**KITKAT WITH GITHUB MATERIAL DIALOG**

[image]

**KITKAT WITH STOCK ALERT DIALOG**

[image]

**LOLLIPOP WITH GITHUB MATERIAL DIALOG**

[image]

**LOLLIPOP WITH STOCK ALERT DIALOG**

[image]

Also this is the library on github installed on the same device its not working on. So its something about my app that is causing this. what could it be

[image]

Comment: Okay. if found the issue but not sure how to fix. i have fitsSystemWindows set to true in my styles. After removing it the dialogs are good. But not my layout is messed up :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

android:fitsSystemWindows="true" was the culprit.

I had that declared in my styles.xml.

Removed it from styles.xml and placed in my layout and it working now.

Comment: I was still running into some weird style issues on Lollipop for my `EditText` (inside a custom view I set) despite following your suggestion. The fix was to set `fitsSystemWindows` to false on the `EditText` in question. Also, padding may be lost in the custom view, using margins instead where possible would solve the issue.

Comment: FYI. If you had fitsSystemWindows applied to a style that you then applied as a theme on an Activity (or the whole Application), then that attribute will be applied to EVERY view on that Activity or Application. Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles. Since a dialog has its own window if you have a dialog off the Activity (or Application) it will have that attribute applied and the text will expand to fit the window. At least, I'm pretty sure that was happening in my case. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and didn't find any fitsSystemWindows on any of my styles.xml.

To solve it i had to wrap the Layout in a FrameLayout and add the margins to the Layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialog_margin_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please enter the email address of the person you would like to follow, this person will be notified." />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```