# Android v21 Theme.Appcompat color accent is ignored, no padding on dialogs

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm using **ActionBarActivity** from the Android 5 SDK and here is my *theme.xml* for v21

```
<style name="AppTheme_Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/abc1</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/abc2</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/abc3</item>
</style>
```

But the colors are ignored, and are replaced by a default teal color and all the dialogs appear without padding.

[image: Problem]

Also, padding is also ignored in other places like custom toast, problem only occurs in lollipop devices.

**Edit:**

The padding problem was due to `fitsSystemWindow` and I got it fixed using
[this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599805/android-alert-dialog-not-styled-properly-on-lollipop?rq=1).

But the accent color problem is still there, and it does not just affect dialogs but the whole app.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

About the accent color. You are using a AppCompat theme so you should remove Android from the namespace inside your theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme_Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/abc1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/abc2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/abc3</item>
</style>
```

About the dialog. AppCompat doesn't support it (as I know).
You can try to use this style in your *values-v21* folder:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="FrameworkRoot.Theme">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AlertDialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/demo_primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/demo_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/theme_accent_1</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE 23/04/2015: SUPPORT LIBRARY V.22.1**

The new `support library v22.1` works with the Dialog.
You can use an [android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html) or the new [AppCompatDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html).

For example:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

AlertDialog.Builder builder =
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.setTitle("Dialog");
            builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            builder.show();
```

And use a style like this:

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#5fa3d0</item>
</style>
```

Otherwise you can define in your current theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- your style -->
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

and then in your code:

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: Ok, first of all it's an honor to have my question answered by the creator of cards-lib. The padding problem was due to `fitsSystemWindow` and I got it fixed using  

[this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599805/android-alert-dialog-not-styled-properly-on-lollipop?rq=1)

Edit : Regarding the accent color it's not just limited to dialogs, but it is ignored everywhere

Comment: Just for reference and in case anyone else runs across this. I had an issue with colorPrimary. I removed the android: and it worked fine, otherwise it was not working. The other values were working, not sure why this one had an issue.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Please note that you do **not** need to pass the style to the `AlertDialog.Builder` if you define a `alertDialogTheme` attribute in your application theme. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29799142/356895).

Comment: in android 4.2.2 its not working dialogs and background of dialog make a look diffrent why? not lookin like lolipop dialogs

Answer (score 22):

**update**

I have applied successfully colors for appCompat dialogs themes , maybe be helpful for someone :

values/style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

...

/* for android 4 - 4.4, we not define alert dialogs style */

</style>
```

values-v21/style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

...

/* define alert dialog style for android 5 */
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AlertDialog</item>

</style>
```

```
 <style name="Theme.AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

    <!--app abar color in Activties Task manager -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>

    <!--copy/paste colors -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_color</item>

    <!--status bar color -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_color</item>


</style>
```

Comment: for me this doesnt work unless I explicitly apply it! With code when initializing ProgressDialog

Answer (score 8):

Current version of AppCompat doesn't apply colorization to AlertDialogs.

Try to use https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs, it works great!