# Lollipop - ProgressDialog color change

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I started porting my app into lollipop. I was able to theme the whole app to a particular color I like but I can't change the color of the ProgressDialog which is always green. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You will need to set up colorAccent in an alert dialog theme. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608390/android-v21-theme-appcompat-color-accent-is-ignored-no-padding-on-dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the asset and change its color with photoshop, or create a new asset and use that as progress dialog.

The new asset can be created like :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360">
<shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">
    <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
    <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="#447a29" 
        android:endColor="#447a29"
        android:angle="0"
         />
</shape>
```

and call this progress.xml for example then use it like this :

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background ="@xml/progress">
```

and you have only to change the start and end color to make it how you want it

Comment: What I am dealing with is not a progress bar, it's a standard ProgressDialog.