# How to change color green in oficial timerpicker?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

This is my code of theme, how change color in dialog timerpicker?

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

[image: Change color in timerpicker oficial]

Comment: You will need to set colorAccent in an alert dialog theme. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608390/android-v21-theme-appcompat-color-accent-is-ignored-no-padding-on-dialogs.