# Widget not tinted on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-widget, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I'm using appcompat v21.0.3 for my app. I did everything like it is written here: [android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

But on Lollipop (and on older devices of course), some widget are not tinted with my accent color. For example:

- SwitchCompat is tinted: [image: switchcompat]
- ListPreference is NOT tinted [image]
- ProgressDialog is NOT tinted [image]

Here's my code:

**build.gradle**

```
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
...
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CET"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        tools:replace="label">
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="CET" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- App branding color -->
    <color name="primary">#a32b30</color>

    <!-- Darker variant for status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <color name="primary_dark">#000000</color>

    <!-- Theme UI constrols like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <color name="accent">#a32b30</color>

</resources>
```

Does someone have an idea?

UPDATE : as of june 2015, still doesn't work but I ended up using https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs. Works really nice for dialogs, including ListPreferences.

Answer (score 30):

Follow the below guide

Unless specified otherwise, all of the below tinting applies to both Lollipop and pre-Lollipop using AppCompat v21. To use the support version of these attributes, remove the android namespace.  For instance, "android:colorControlNormal" becomes "colorControlNormal".  These attributes will be propagated to their corresponding attributes within the android namespace for devices running Lollipop.  Any exceptions to this will be noted by including the "android:" prefix.

```
All Clickable Views:
-----------
* ripple effect (Lollipop only) -- "colorControlHighlight"

Status Bar:
------------
* background (Lollipop only) - "colorPrimaryDark"

Navigation Bar:
----------------
* background (Lollipop only) - "android:navigationBarColor"

EditText:
----------
* underline (unfocused) -- "colorControlNormal"
* underline overlay (focus) -- "colorAccent"
* cursor -- "colorAccent"
* text color -- "android:textColorPrimary"

CheckBox:
----------
* box unchecked -- "colorControlNormal"
* box checked -- "colorAccent"

RadioButton:
-------------
* unselected -- "colorControlNormal"
* selected -- "colorAccent"
* ripple effect (Lollipop only) -- "colorControlHighlight"

SwitchCompat:
-------------
* thumb switch off -- "colorSwitchThumbNormal"
* thumb switch on -- "colorAccent"
* track overlay (when switched on) -- "colorAccent"

Spinner:
---------
* indicator (not pressed) -- "colorControlNormal"
* indicator (pressed) -- "colorAccent"
* selected entry text color (Lollipop only) -- "android:textColorPrimary"

ActionBar:
-----------
* background -- "colorPrimary"
* title color -- "android:textColorPrimary"
* overflow icon -- "android:textColorPrimary"
* up button -- "android:textColorPrimary"
* action icons -- "android:textColorPrimary" †
* overflow menu background -- "android:colorBackground"
* overflow text color -- "android:textColorPrimary"

Toolbar (Theme Overlay should be used):
----------------------------------------
* background -- must be set manually in XML. Can do (android:background="?attr/colorPrimary")
* overflow icon -- "android:textColorPrimary"
* navigation icon -- "android:textColorPrimary" †
* action icons -- "android:textColorPrimary" †
* overflow menu background -- "android:colorBackground"
* overflow text color -- "android:textColorPrimary"
```

P.S. tinting by default only works with whitelisted stock action icons (see `TintManager` source code).  For instance, the back arrow icon `"abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"` is tinted, but copying that exact file and renaming it will result in the icon not being tinted while taking a random image and renaming it to `"abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"` will result in it being tinted. Tinting can be done in XML in Lollipop by creating a `<bitmap>` xml file in drawable and applying the `"android:tint"` attribute. This icon can be used in both Lollipop and pre-Lollipop, but it will only be tinted in Lollipop.  Tinting of action icons can also be done programmatically using a `ColorFilter`.

[Source](https://gist.github.com/seanKenkeremath/c945c39cdf92af138395)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, but it doesn't help: ProgressDialog should be tinted on Lollipop and it isn't, whatever values I use (I tried to add every value (colorControlNormal, ...) it doesn't change: some elements are green.

Comment: Try doing this on one specific element (button) for test `android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"` `android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"`

Comment: I will try that to check, but the problem is not on widgets I use myself, but on widgets I don't have access to: a standard ProgressDialog, and and ListPreference used in a PreferenceFragment. So I can't add this element on these...

Answer (score 12):

You should generally use your own progress bar instead of a dialog and then you could make a tinted version that works on both L and pre-L like so:

```
public class TintedProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
    public TintedProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TintedProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TintedProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to change the color in the dialog you could find the nested progress bar probably at `dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.progess)`

Answer (score 5):

To changing color of Progress Dialog drawable, I've used following workaround: I've created AppCompat alert dialog base style

```
    <style name="CustomAppCompatAlertDialogStyle"    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/defaultColor</item>
            <item name="android:indeterminateTint">?attr/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:indeterminateTintMode">src_in</item>
    </style>
```

And then apply these theme to Progress Dialog:

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.CustomAppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```

Answer (score 3):

It only answers part of your question, but the progress bar style from the appcompat library doesn't pick up the accent color on lollipop yet, even outside of `ProgressDialog`.

You'll need to set it up yourself, for example with this style:

```
<style name="TintedProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateTint">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateTintMode">src_in</item>
</style>
```

that you can then apply to a `ProgressBar` or a `ContentLoadingProgressBar`. (note that a parent element the progress bar is inflated in will obviously have to apply the theme defining the `colorAccent` attribute ; otherwise use a direct color resource)

If you want to integrate the progress bar in a dialog, <s>since I don't think `ProgressDialog` supports customization of its progress bar beyond the type and drawable, you may have to set up an `AlertDialog` with a progress bar applying the above theme, or simply go with a custom dialog I guess</s> you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31336796/3055345) to apply the above progress-bar-related attributes to a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Try attribute `colorControlActivated`:

themes.xml

```
<style name="CET" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#a32b30</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, anything in a Dialog is not automatically tinted in Lollipop (yet). Checkout [material-dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs), a library to do this automatically for you (but it only supports API 14+).

Checkout answers from a similar question: [Android v21 Theme.Appcompat color accent is ignored, no padding on dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608390/android-v21-theme-appcompat-color-accent-is-ignored-no-padding-on-dialogs)

Comment: So to have tinted dialog on Lollipop I must NOT use AppCompat?

Comment: Use AppCompat if you need to support lower level APIs, if only Lollipop then no need. The library I refer to is independent of AppCompat, I think you can use them together.