# AlertDialog customize background

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

There is problem with my styles. I would like prepare AlertDialog totaly colered in yellow without shadow. Here is code below:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(About.this, R.style.Mystyle);

 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
 <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Mystyle.Dialog</item>
 <style name="Mystyle.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
```

Any help? Actually messsage is in white color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797134/how-to-use-and-style-the-new-alertdialog-from-appcompat-22-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `AlertDialog` and apply custom style still it will display black shadow though you have set `android:windowBackground` transparent.

So you need to use `Dialog` and apply that custom style to it which will solve your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797134/how-to-use-and-style-the-new-alertdialog-from-appcompat-22-1