# UserDialogs custom UI in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using [UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/) library in my `MVVMCross` project. The following code has been tested and works perfectly fine, I could able to see Loading Dialog. The issue that I have, how could I able to change the color of the circular loading progress in order to match with my theme?

```
private async Testing ()
{
   using (Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Loading("Loading..."))
   {
     await PutTaskDelay();
   }
}

async Task PutTaskDelay()
{
     await Task.Delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your native code (iOS/Android) you have to

- inherit `MyProgressDialog` form `ProgressDialog` (see https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/src/Acr.UserDialogs/Platforms/ios/ProgressDialog.cs)
- override the `Refresh` method and customize the created dialog as you want
- inherit `MyUserDialogs` from `UserDialogsImpl`
- override the `CreateDialogInstance` and make it return `new MyProgressDialog()` instead of `new ProgressDialog()`
- register `MyUserDialogs` for `IUserDialogs` (`Mvx.Register...`)

Comment: any idea for the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162412/userdialogs-loading-does-not-show-up

Answer (score 2):

You can supply AppCompat dialog themes using styles.xml:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/Base.Theme.Dialog.App</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Base.Theme.AlertDialog.App</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.Dialog.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.AlertDialog.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

This will change the color of the progress widget in the ACR.UserDialogs library, along with the negative/positive/neutral action buttons. See more information here: [How to Use and Style the new AlertDialog from appCompat 22.1 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797134/how-to-use-and-style-the-new-alertdialog-from-appcompat-22-1-and-above)