# Why the accent color in the popup dialogue view(created dynamically i.e by java code) is green whereas I have different color in my application theme?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, colors, dialog

So I have set the colors i.e `primary`, `primaryDark`, `accentColor` in the style.xml manually and I can see whole application is taking the colors properly such as toolbar is having the appropriate colors, texts are having appropriate colors. Now, when I am creating a dialogue by java code the colors of the buttons within fragment are very much different from the colors my whole application is having. So why the dialogue is having such different style than of my application. This question will help me in understanding themes, so please answer in such way i.e. behaviour of the `themes` in android.

**EDIT**

The code I am using in styles.xml in my application.

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

The code I am using in colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#675217</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#261e09</color>
  <color name="colorAccent">#ffcb39</color>
  <color name="colorTabLayout">#a68425</color>
</resources>
```

Here are the screenshots of the things I am facing.

First Screen:-

[image: Every thing is fine all the elements have appropriate colors]

Every thing is fine all the elements have appropriate colors

Second Screen:-

[image: Pop up fragment]

Here The color of the buttons in the pop up dialogue is not the accent color that I have added in styles.xml. Otherwise in first screen you can see different accent color in button text in `cardview`.

Comment: Depends on how you implemented your style.xml, sample code I guess

Comment: this color is by default picked from application level default theme applied. If you are looking to change the color check for create a separate theme whose parent class is dialog, there you can define color and other definitions to that dialog type.

Comment: Can you post your style code?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I have added the style.xml

Comment: @AshishSrivastava I have added the code and elaborated more.

Comment: @AnkushBist Yeah the color was picked from default theme. How can we force it to use the colors provided in the application resources.

Comment: dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(COLOR_I_WANT);

Comment: this is the actual and easiest code to change button text color.

Comment: @AnkushBist Yeah your suggestion is right but I am seeking for other thing like how can we set the themes for such kind of views not setting the colors manually.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797134/how-to-use-and-style-the-new-alertdialog-from-appcompat-22-1-and-above

Comment: @AnkushBist Thanks! brother. Thanks! a lot.