# Android dialog theme makes setContentView crash the application

Tags: java, android, view, crash, android-theme

I'm applying this theme from manifest :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.rate.MyActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
```

With this the application crash on setContentView() of MyActivity. If I remove it there is no crash but I need this theme

In the activity onCreate() i'm doing this :

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rate);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Even if I remove the first and third lines the applicatio ncrash the same way. It's really the dialog theme that's causing the crash

How can I set it so that Android accept it ?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/29798616/3946958

Comment: I can't refactor it as a dialog, it needs to stay as an Activity.

Comment: There is no log the application just crash without error/warning

Comment: Try `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`.

Comment: Yes that was it, actually I found it just before you told me ;) but you can make the answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Ah just one thing.... The name of the application appear at the top of the dialog. How can I remove it ?

Comment: Just like the answer given below, use `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` instead of `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` for that you are using a **compat** theme for your activity. @An-droid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` as the theme of your activity to avoid 
compatibility problem.
The activity will be presented as a dialog.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
</activity>
```

As for the title, you can use `setTitle("Hola!");` to change it.
If you wanna remove the title, just call:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

for `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"`,
and:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

for `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`.

Comment: It's been a while but yes if I remember correctly, AppCompat was the solution o/