# Android colorAccent is ignored in the Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am creating a dialog box using custom layout but in layout `colorAccent` is completely ignored and replaced by default teal color. I have changed my theme according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609009/7130121). but still not working. I can add theme to at the time of creating dialog by its constructor but I want do it only by theme so it affects every dialog in my app.Any help appreciated thanks here is my theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

My dialog box look like this image [image] Edittext cursor is ignoring my colorAccent.

Comment: You have to define custom style then add accent color matching the your app's color Accent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Define style while initiating diaolog in activity.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, R.style.DialogStyle);
```

Comment: i want to know why `<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Dialog</item>` not working

Comment: I have edited my answer. Why you have to use Theme.Dialog ? Isn't it more easier to refer directly to the style name for alertDialog ?

Comment: I am using dialog not alertdialog

Comment: also my theme parent is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`

Comment: Sorry, I am getting confused. Then why are you using the parent as "Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert" ? Shouldn't you use parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" instead for Dialog ?

Comment: i used both of theme

Comment: I've reverted the answer again. :p If you are using Dialog then you may try  out my answer. Let me know if it helps. :)

Comment: there is no problem with my constructor

Comment: solved my problem by using <item `name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Theme.Dialog</item>` instaed of `<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Dialog</item>`

Comment: mention this to your answer so it will helpfull to others