# How to set default color of progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to change the color of my `ProgressBar` throughout my entire app. The Android documentation indicates that if I am using `AppCompat`, it will use the `colorAccent` for the color of the progress bars. But it's not using it in my app. Here is my `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

<!-- Application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
</style>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>

<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>

<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Login" parent="AppTheme.Base">
<item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/gray</item>
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/med_gray</item>

<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Menu" parent="AppTheme.Base">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="AppTheme.Base">
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="login_button_style">
<item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_small</item>
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Check
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608390/android-v21-theme-appcompat-color-accent-is-ignored-no-padding-on-dialogs) answer. It is similar to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the suggestion given by @RuslanMatveev as a comment doesn't work, you can try the following.

```
<style name="MyProgressBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/colorAccent</item> 
</style>
```

and then set the following paraments inside your AppTheme.Base

```
<item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/MyProgressBar</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/MyProgressBar</item
```

---

**UPDATE**

In case the solution above change the shape of your progress bar you can try to just add the following line to your AppTheme.base

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
```

Comment: This almost worked for me. It changed the color, but it changed my spinning progress bar into a horizontal bar.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can just remove the .Horizontal in front of the @style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar and it should work

Comment: If I remove it, the color doesn't change anymore

Comment: Can you try to just set <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item> on your AppTheme.base and remove the rest?

Comment: Yes that's the only thing that worked for me! Append it to your post - it wouldn't hurt to leave your original answer there too since that works for the horizontal bar.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

- You have to create `progress` in your `drawable`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="15"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@android:color/white"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="@color/colorYellow"
            android:startColor="@color/colorYellow"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

---

- Now you can use `progress` to change your color of `progressbar` by using this

---

```
<ProgressBar
             android:id="@+id/progressBar"
             style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" >
         </ProgressBar>
```

Comment: From what I've been reading around here, this works for many people, but doesn't for me. Ruan_Lopes answer is the only thing that works for me.