# white background under alert dialog box

Tags: android

Why am i getting this white background under my alert dialogbox. I been trying to figure out the problem for an hour and had no luck. Can someone please help me?

Also, why is that the left and right sides of the title has a little dark shade.

[image]

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //progressDialog.dismiss();
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        String status = json.getString("status");
        String message = json.getString("message");
        if(status.equals("true")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, status);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setMessage(message)
                   .setTitle("Error")
                   .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   }).create().show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Custom Dialog view

Comment: on which emulator or device did you run your app?

Comment: try setting theme like, AlertDialog.Builder(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);

Comment: @Harry, not working i still get the white background.

Comment: @yaa110 I'm running on nexus 4

Comment: I found the issue. I've added <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item> to the style. I removed that line and the white background is gone. weird

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Import 
 **android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog** instead of **android.app.AlertDialog**

Answer (score 14):

Change your code as -

```
 Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
    alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alertDialog.show();
```

Or you can add theme to your existing code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
```

Answer (score 7):

When initializing dialog builder, pass second parameter as the theme.
So Change

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
```

---

It is old answer, now

Import `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` instead of `android.app.AlertDialog`

as given in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34584907/991085).

Comment: it works, but now the dividers between title and message and ok button are also gone. :)

Comment: For this issue please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599805/android-alert-dialog-not-styled-properly-on-lollipop

Answer (score 6):

if you can access Dialog class, try this:

```
 alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

before:

[image: dialog_before]

after:

[image: dialog_after]