# AlertDialog broken layout on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, galaxy

I'm experiencing problems with the following approach to create an AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(R.string.deletion_title)
    .setMessage(R.string.options_deleteExternalConfirm)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Utils.deleteExternalDir();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null);
alertDialog.show();
```

While the dialog looks ok on most devices, it has layout problems on others (namely the Galaxy S4 - GT-I9505 with Android 5.0.1), see attached picture:[image: Broken layout on Galaxy S4] .
**What is the reason for that and how can I fix it?**

(Other than adding a padding to a custom dialog when `Build.PRODUCT.equals("GT-I9505")` since there might be phones out there which have the same issue but which are unknown to me)

Comment: i think something wrong with the phone, can you restart phone and try or with another phone with same type ?

Comment: Restarting did not change anything. Organizing another device of the same type is a good idea

Comment: yeah....check and let me know if it is working...if i will face this type of issue, i can follow up with the same.

Comment: I found out that the reason is the android:fitsSystemWindows property - it seems to be a little buggy.

Comment: so did you set this property or what ? what exactly was the solution ?

Comment: Well, the solution was to remove the property for now. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26600484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that is was a problem with android:fitsSystemWindows and Android Lollipop like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600484).